# SSIS push and pull performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, ssis, business-intelligence

After reading https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46289/which-one-is-more-efficient-select-from-linked-server-or-insert-into-linked-ser I wonder if this is true also for SSIS?

For example, I have 2 servers (A and B) and SSIS solution which extract data from A and load it to B  (A->B). What's the difference in performance, between deploying SSIS package on server A or B?

Comment: Assuming both servers are identical, I would think little to no different. Just about everything in SSIS is done in memory, so if one had more it might be faster. If i had to guess I would say deploy to A would be faster( but this just a guess)

Comment: Both servers are SQL Server.